# Is it possible to populate data from a web service to PerformancePoint dashboard reports?

Tags: performancepoint

I need to populate data from a web service and show the result in an analytic chart using PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer.

I came across this [SDK](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ppsSdkRefSample) to customize our own data source provider and custom report. I tried to change the report type as below.

```
reportview.TypeName = ReportViewNames.OLAPGrid;
reportview.SubTypeId = ReportViewNames.OLAPGrid;
```

But I don't get the desired result. How can I render dataset values as an analytic chart? Let me know if this is even possible or not?

**Update** - To be more clear about my requirement. I just want to get data from web service and show it in BI Dashboard analytic reports. I tried to  customize SDK to customize datasource provider and I was able to set my custom data provider. After this I need to populate data with the ReportView. There are many options with ReportViewName but I didn't was not able to bind this data with OLAPGrid. Can anyone show me any link/provide more information on this.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this that you can provide? Or can you edit the question with any more information? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PerformancePoint analytic reports only consume OLAP data (i.e. from SSAS or PowerPivot).

6/13/2011 - And this page has a code example for programmatically creating an analytic chart: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.performancepoint.scorecards.store.spdatastore.createreportview.aspx

Comment: Agree !! There one more way, I haven't tried, but can be a good solution; using Power Pivot as stating and also to build cubes,  read the date webservice  into PowerPivot, build the cube and design the Reports in Performance Point